# React useEffect warning in MERN App: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I'm getting this warning somewhere here, but I'm not sure why. I need some help to resolve that what is causing the problem. The products are fine with adding to the database, but I can't show the new added product until I logout with the user and login again, then the cart of the user is showing updated:

```
const Cart = props => {

    const [products, addedProducts] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        addedProducts(user.cart)
    }, [])
    
    const onRemove = () => toast.error('Product removed from cart!', {
        position: "top-right",
        autoClose: 2000,
        hideProgressBar: true,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        draggable: true,
        progress: undefined,
    });
    
    const handleRemove = (id) => {
        fetch(`${API}/cart/${id}/delete`, {
            method: 'POST'
        }).then(() => {
            onRemove();
            const timer = setTimeout(() => {
                props.history.push('/cart')
            }, 500)
            return () => clearTimeout(timer)
        })
    };
```

Here is my cartController:

```
router.post('/usercart', async (req, res) => {
    const [userId, cart] = req.body
    console.log(req.body, 'ccccc')
    try {
        console.log(req.body, 'aft')
        let userCart = await cartService.cart([userId, cart])
        res.status(200).json({userCart})
        } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).json({ error: error })
    }
})
```

Here is my cartService:

```
const cart = async ([userId, cart]) => {
    let userCart = await User.updateOne({_id: userId}, {$push: {cart: cart}})
    return userCart
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you need a useEffect? You basically only populate a state. So directly write:

```js
const [products, setProducts] = useState(user?.cart || [])
```

If I may, I'd advise you to rename `addedProduct` into `setProducts`. If your code grows, one could easily mix-up the variables names. `addedProducts` sounds like a variable, and not like an update function.

Comment: I've got the same effect

Comment: Is it possible to be cuz I'm saving the user model in localstorage for now ?